# Why is the word "pepper" used for both capsicum (e.g. bell pepper) and piper (e.g. black pepper)?

Tags: nouns, plants

They clearly look different and they don't have that much in common. Taxonomically, they also belong to different families

[image: black and white pepper kernels]
[image: a green, a red, and a yellow bell pepper]

Answer (score 4):

The [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=pepper) states that Latin *piper* is the source of the English word (as well as “German *Pfeffer,* Italian *pepe,* French *poivre,* Old Church Slavonic *pipru,* Lithuanian *pipiras,* Old Irish *piobhar,* Welsh *pybyr,* etc.”). It's ultimately from Sanskrit and originally referred to the Old World's *Piper* genus.

The New World's [*Capsicum*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsicum) genus came to be called “pepper” in the 16c. because of its similarities to black pepper. While they don't look much alike, they have common culinary uses. This is somewhat like the use of *corn* to refer to [maize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maize), although that appellation isn't entirely analogous.

Comment: what do you mean "common culinary uses"?

Comment: @LouisRhys They're both used to season food, with similar tastes.

Comment: Where in the world are the words *piper* and *bell pepper* used?

Comment: @Tristan *Piper* is the Latin name for pepper. *Bell pepper* is the common term in North America; no one at the grocery will know what a *capsicum* is.

Comment: choster, thanks. I doubt anyone in the UK would know what any of those three, are. I hadn't heard of them. The words *pepper* and *peppers* are used here.